# Arabic Language MS ACCESS

Tags: database, ms-access, arabic

I have an ACCESS database in which characters are Arabic but displayed like this "ÇáÓíÏ ÇáÇãíä ÇáÚÇã ááÍßæãÉ" , is there any solution to this problem please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a collation problem.

```
ALTER DATABASE (Database name here) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS ;
```

> All databases have a default collation (which can be set when creating or altering a database. This collation is used for all metadata in the database, as well as the default for all string columns within the database. Users can choose a different collation for any particular column by using the COLLATE clause.

Go [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929080.aspx), for further reading.

Comment: Please i used : 
ALTER DATABASE Requette COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS ;
But i keep getting the following error (Msgbox : Syntax Error in Alter Table Statement) Thanks for help

Comment: Can you add the full error message in a comment so I can see ?